# merge in python by certain columns from list of files

Tags: pandas, select, merge, col

I have a directory with >200 tab-delimited files all same structure (column #s, column headers)

```
+------+--------------+-------+-------+-----------+------+---------+
| col1 |     col2     | col2  | col3  | p_val_adj | col4 |  gene   |
+------+--------------+-------+-------+-----------+------+---------+
|    0 |  1.980029448 | 0.978 | 0.124 |         0 |    0 | TRDV2   |
|    0 |  1.812616859 | 0.979 | 0.176 |         0 |    0 | TRGV9   |
|    0 |  1.442023797 | 0.688 |  0.09 |         0 |    0 | TRDC    |
|    0 | -1.834847304 | 0.021 | 0.735 |         0 |    0 | TRAV1-2 |
+------+--------------+-------+-------+-----------+------+---------+
```

My goal is to generate an output file that contains the "gene" as first column and merge all the "avg_logFC" column data from all the files. For non-overlapping genes, leave the value blank.

**The steps to be done:**
1) read all files in the directory ending with .txt [done] ex: File1.txt , File2.txt, File3.txt
2) use column "gene" as index_col [done]
3) merge the files into a single dataframe [error]
4) the column header instead of avg_logFC should reflect the file name

**Here is what I did so far:**

```
args = parse_args()
    path=os.getcwd() #opens the path
    allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")    #reads all files in the path with .txt
    result = pd.read_csv(allFiles[0], sep="\t", index_col=["gene"]) #index by gene
    for i in range(1,len(allFiles)): #iterates over remaining files; note first file is 0.
        print i
        df = pd.read_csv(allFiles[i], sep="\t", index_col=["gene"])
        result = pd.merge(result, df, right_index=False, left_index=True, how='inner')
result.to_csv(args.output+".xls", sep="\t", na_rep="")
```

**I am unable to get the desired output which is exemplified below.**

```
+----------+-------+-------+--------+
|  genes   | File1 | File2 | File 3 |
+----------+-------+-------+--------+
| TRDV2    |   0.5 |    12 |      2 |
| TRGV9    |     2 |     2 |        |
| TRDC     |    -2 |     3 |      1 |
| TRAV1-2  |       |    21 |     -5 |
| CD8A     |  0.24 |       |     -2 |
| TRBV20-1 |     3 |     1 |     -2 |
| TRBC1    |   0.2 |       |      3 |
| FCGR3A   |     1 |     2 |      4 |
+----------+-------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that the `how` should be `outer` and not `inner` otherwise you will get  only the genes that are in all dataframes, also I'm not sure why `right_index` is False if you want to merge on genes that is index. The second thing that is not clear is where is the column avg_logFC because it is not in your example, I assume it is a column and if so, you should not `merge` the full `df` but select only this column before the `merge`. Finally, using `merge` at every iteration, is not really efficient (not sure if it is a problem here). I think it would be better to use `concat` here like:

```
args = parse_args()
path=os.getcwd() #opens the path
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")    #reads all files in the path with .txt

result = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, sep="\t", index_col=["gene"], usecols=['avg_logFC'])
                    for file in allFiles], 
                   axis=1, keys=range(len(allFiles)))\
           .reset_index()

result.to_csv(args.output+".xls", sep="\t", na_rep="")
```

Not sure of the exact output, but it should be pretty close to what you are looking for. Maybe you need to `rename` the column before the `reset_index`

Comment: I tried it , it is giving invalid syntax. Not sure if this works.

Comment: @BioProgram if you give a bit details on where it fails, I may help you. Also I realized that in `to_csv`, the extension to the file is `".xls"` while it should be `".csv"`